# How to get a variable from a different script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I want to access a variable that I initialized in a different script. How do I access the variable? I'm using tags to access the variable. I want to access the `paddleIsAlive` variable.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        alive = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Paddle").GetComponent<PaddleScript>();
    }


    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collider)
    {  
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && collider.gameObject.tag == "Paddle" && alive.paddleIsAlive == true)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error even though I initialize it in `start()`:

```
the name alive doesn't exist in the current context
```

Comment: You should declare an `alive` field/property somewhere in the script.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a variable, you have to explicitly set its type. Since you want your variable `alive` to keep a reference to another script `PaddleScript`, its type should be `PaddleScript`:

```
public void Start() {
    PaddleScript alive = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Paddle").GetComponent<PaddleScript>();
}
```

However, if you make it this way, i.e. declare it in the `Start()` method, it will only be viewed in this very function. But since you also need to use it in the `OnTriggerStay2D()` function, you have to declare this variable outside of any functions, like this:

```
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
   private PaddleScript alive; // Variable declaration

    public void Start()
    {
        alive = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Paddle").GetComponent<PaddleScript>(); // Variable initializing
    }

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collider)
    {  
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && collider.gameObject.tag == "Paddle" && alive.paddleIsAlive == true)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a script in collider. Make sure the variable is **`public`**.

```cs
public class PaddleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float PaddleLength = 2; // for example..

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // ..
    }
}
```

If the above script is connected to your paddle, you don't need `GameObject.Find` in Start and just use `TryGetComponent`:

```cs
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collider)
{  
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (collider.TryGetComponent(out PaddleScript paddle))
        {
            Debug.Log(paddle.PaddleLength); // for ex field..
            paddle.DoSomething(); // for ex method..
        }
    }
}
```